# How to Avoid Repeating Passport.JS Code Used in Multiple Express.JS Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I just started using Passport.js in my Express app for creating a API with authenticated routes.

**Question:** If I have 2 routes defined in `routes/animals.js` and `routes/locations.js` which uses Passport to protect certain API requests, where I need to create a `passport` object and run `passport.use(new BearerStrategy...)` before i can use `passport.authenticate` later in the code.

How can I avoid repeating the `passport.use(new BearerStrategy...)` code in all the routes file? Or is it better to repeat them?

**routes/animals.js**

```
var passport = require("passport");
passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
function(token, done) {
    User.findOne({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
    return done(null, user, { scope: 'all' });
    });
}
));

router.get('/', 
    passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
    function(req, res, next) {
        Animal.find(function(err, animals) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(animals)
        })
})
```

**app.js**

```
var animalsRouter = require('./routes/animals');

app.use('/api/animals', animalsRouter);

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js modules are [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)-like. Meaning whenever you do `require('passportjs')`, you are getting back the same instance you imported in another file.

For your case, in every route file, you are importing the *same* Passport instance every time. So you only need to define your Passport configuration once.

So for example, define you `BearerStrategy` in another file:

**bearer-strategy.js**

```
module.exports = new BearerStrategy((token, done) => {
  // ...
});
```

Then in your main `app.js`, configure Passport only once:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const bearerStrategy = require('./bearer-strategy.js');

const app = express();

// Only need to do this once
passport.use(bearerStrategy);
```

But now you need to protect your API routes *and* avoid repeating yourself. You can do this, by applying the Passport middleware to `/api/**` instead of `/api/myRouter` for every router. So your animals router can be:

**routes/animals.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json(req.user));

module.exports = router;
```

Now we need an API router which just mounts all the other routers:

**routes/api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const animalRouter = require('./animals.js');

router.use('/animals', animalRouter);
// other routers

module.exports = router;
```

Now finally, we can mount them in one shot *and* secure them with Passport **once**:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const bearerStrategy = require('./bearer-strategy.js');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/api.js')

const app = express();

passport.use(bearerStrategy);

app.use('/api', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), apiRouter);
```

---

As an aside, all plugins/whatever for Express are just [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).